# Implementing a program that encrypts messages using Vigenère’s cipher, C

Tags: c, cs50

i tried to make a program, that is using Vigenere's cipher. Every 3th letter is wrong. Can somebody give me a hint? Thank you for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

int n = 0;
int j = 0;
int p;
int l;
int x = 0;


if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("missing command-line argument\n");
    return 1;
} else
{
    printf("plaintext: ");
}    

string text = get_string();
string key = (argv[1]);

printf("ciphertext: ");


for (j = 0, x = 0, n = strlen(text); j < n; j++)
{

  p = (((text[j] - 65) + ((key[x] - 65) % strlen(key))) % 26) + 65;
  l = (((text[j] - 97) + ((key[x] - 97) % strlen(key))) % 26) + 97;

if(isalpha(text[j]))
{
  if( isupper (text[j]))
  {
    printf("%c", p);
    x++;
  }
  if( islower (text[j]))
  {
    printf("%c", l);
    x++;
  }
}else
{
  printf("%c", text[j]);
}
 if(x == strlen(key))
 {
  x = 0;
 }
 }
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
 }
```

I can't figure put if int p, int l are wrong or if it is a other problem.

hear is a input/output exempel

:) encrypts "a" as "a" using "a" as keyword

:( encrypts "barfoo" as "caqgon" using "baz" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: casgop\n"

:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: CaSGoo\n"

:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: CASGOP\n"

:( encrypts "world!$?" as "xoqmd!$?" using "baz" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: xosmd!$?\n"

:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "xoqmd, rby gflkp!" using "baz" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: xosmd, tby iflmp!\n"

Comment: What input are you providing and what output do you expect? Code could also do with being indented better cos it's not that readable.

Comment: @ChrisTurner My guess is that the key passed as an argument (argv[1]) is a string of 3 characters length.
acipi9 Try with if(x == strlen(key)+1)

Comment: @J.A.I.L. better to have actual examples of input/output than guesses :)

Comment: hear is a input/output exempel hear is a input/output exempel   encrypts "a" as "a" using "a" as keyword
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "caqgon" using "baz" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: casgop\n"
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: CaSGoo\n"
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: CASGOP\n"

Comment: *encrypts "barfoo" as "caqgon" using "baz" as keyword \ expected output, but not "ciphertext: casgop\n"* - So your code encrypts `r` with a key of `z` to `q`. And you think that encrypting `r` with a key of `z` should be `s`? But encrypting `r` with a key of `b` would yield `s`, no? Can you explain *why* you think your output is wrong?!

Comment: the "generatet" coded Alphabet has +1 letter it repeats after z -2 letters to x and jumps than back to:  abc....xyzxabc....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the wikipedia description of the cipher, breaking the maths down, you have 17 (R) + 25 (Z) mod 26 which is 16 (Q)...so basically encrypting any letter with Z would get you the letter before which for R would be Q.

But your code isn't doing that maths - it's got a spurious "% strlen(key)" in there in the wrong place which is why you think it should be an S. You want that inside the indexing of `key` like so and as a result you can ditch the variable `x`

```
p = (((text[j] - 'A') + (key[j % strlen(key)] - 'A')) % 26) + 'A';
l = (((text[j] - 'a') + (key[j % strlen(key)] - 'a')) % 26) + 'a';
```

Also, you'll notice I replaced 65 & 97 with characters as that makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: it helped with lowercase

Comment: uppercase is ./vigenere ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
plaintext: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
ciphertext: [\]^_`aHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`aHIJKLMNOPQRSTU

Comment: yes, that is because if your key is a different case to your plaintext it'll get half of each equation wrong - the cipher isn't really designed for mixed case text. But it's easily fixed - just work out what each letter is in the key and plaintext separately and then do the maths on the results.